# Why JSONModel do like this

Tags: objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I like JSONModel library and its concept. While just looking on the implementation met with some doubts.
in the initialiser

```
-(instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)err
```

the parameter data is converted to string and passing to next initialiser

```
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(JSONModelError**)err
```

in this method its converting back to `NSData` for using with `NSJSONSerialization`

Why didn't do something like this..

```
-(instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)err
{
    //not converting nsdata to an nsstring -- using it directly
    if (!data.length) return nil;


    //read the json
    JSONModelError* initError = nil;
    id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&initError];

    if (initError) {
        if (err) *err = [JSONModelError errorBadJSON];
        return nil;
    }

    //init with dictionary
    id objModel = [self initWithDictionary:obj error:&initError];
    if (initError && err) *err = initError;
    return objModel;

}
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(JSONModelError**)err
{
    //check for nil input
    if (!string) {
        if (err) *err = [JSONModelError errorInputIsNil];
        return nil;
    }

    //create an instance
    JSONModelError* initError = nil;

    id objModel = [self initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:encoding] error:&initError];
    if (initError && err) *err = initError;
    return objModel;
}
```

Does this make sense?, shall we avoid two conversions?

Comment: Hah! This looks like a great catch. To be honest - initWithData: was added in a hurry to add support for NSURLSession when iOS 7 came out and I  overlooked that there's a redundant data < - > string conversion. Will fix

Comment: lwhile asking this question I thought it may be a blunder. can i open a pull requet for this?

Comment: @MarinTodorov I just created a pull request. Could you please have a look on that

Comment: will look into it, but on the road right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved thanks to @Johnykutty :)

The relevant commit is here: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/commit/02619d9d3bad92bc0ea6b75a45cc69d16b5e0801

Now running any of the initializers will avoid converting data types back-and-forth:

- `-initWithString:error:`
- `-initWithString:usingEncoding:error:`
- `-initWithDictionary:error:`
- `-initWithData:error:`

Comment: awesome, great to have a real answer for everyone that ends up on this page!